# blocks and define override in hugo theme

Tags: hugo

I face an issue when using Hugo v0.16 and creating a theme.

Basically I define a `list.html` file with a `{{ block }}` entry in order to override it later in my taxonomy

After reading the documentation [here](https://gohugo.io/templates/list/#taxonomy-lists) it seems that a good entrypoint should be in the `/themes/THEME/layouts/_default/taxonomy.html`
file. But when I render my `index.html` it uses the define in the taxonomy file. I think this is a bug but I just want to be sure.

here are the basic content of my files:

_default/list.html

```
<h1>Foo {{ block "bar"}}{{ end }}</h1>
```

_default/taxonomy.html

```
 {{ define "bar" }}Bar{{ end }}
```

What I was expecting:

index.html

```
<h1>Foo </h1>
```

/taxonomy_plural/taxonomy_term/

```
<h1>Foo Bar</h1>
```

But the index.html looks like /taxonomy_plural/taxonomy_term/ which is not what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question as someone gave me a solution

As explained here https://discuss.gohugo.io/t/blocks-and-define-override-in-hugo-theme/3543, what I want to do is possible if I use a baseof*.html.

So here is the final structure:

_default/baseof.html

```
 <h1>Foo {{ block "bar"}}{{ end }}</h1>
```

`index.html` is empty and `_default/taxonomy.html` contains

```
{{ define "bar" }}Bar{{ end }}
```

and it provides what I needed